# Permission based on field value that user POSTs

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework

A simplified view of my models:

```py
# models.py 

class User(models.Model):
    first_name = models.CharField()
    last_name = models.CharField()
    team = models.ForeignKey('Team')
    ...

class Team(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField()

class ToDo(models.Model):
    task = models.CharField()
    description = models.TextField()
    owner = models.ForeignKey('User')
```

```py
# serializers.py

class ToDoSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    id = serializers.ReadOnlyField()

    class Meta:
        model = ToDo
        fields = '__all__'
```

I want to create a POST endpoint to add a new `ToDo` object based on the following logic:

- Users can create `ToDo` items for themselves
- Users can create `ToDo` items for others in their Team
- Users cannot create `ToDo` items for others who aren't in their team

**Question: Where do is write this logic**

I attempted this by using Permission classes but I don't know if that is the best place to do this

```py
# views.py

class ToDoViewSet(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
    serializer_class = ToDoSerializer
    permission_classes = (CanAddToDo,)



# permissions.py

class CanAddToDo(BasePermission):
    def has_permission(self, request, view):
        owner_id = request.data.get('owner', None)

        # owner_id must be set
        if not owner_id:
            return False

        # User can create items if owner is themselves or someone in their team
        if User.objects.get(pk=owner_id).team == request.user.team:
            return True

        return False

    def has_object_permission(self, request, view, obj):
        """
        Checks if the user owns the todo to edit
        """
        return obj.owner == request.user
```

What's bugging me about that is I'm not using the serialized data and instead, getting the raw owner's id from the request and making a query in the permissions object to do my validation/permission

Other options could be to do this validation in the views' `def perform_create(self, serializer):` function or in the serializer its self.

Comment: The Permission check and Authentication checks should take place before any action on the particular view, which is the DRF way. If you want serialized data to be passed to the Permission class, it's become little bit complex (I think...)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is another way to look at this; validation for owner

In your serializer for ToDo you can write a validation for owner field

```
class ToDoSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    id = serializers.ReadOnlyField()

    class Meta:
        model = ToDo
        fields = '__all__'

    def validate_owner(self, val):
        owner = val
        request = self.context.get('request', None)
        # it is possible you are using serializer outside an api view 
        # in which case reqeust will not be present in the serializer context
        if request:
            if owner.team != request.user.team:
                raise serializers.ValidationError('you can only create todos for'
                                                  'yourself or your team members')
        return val
```

This is works well for creation. But for update or delete you need to check the current owner on the todo object. Which can be done in a permission class. You can use the `id` from the request url to get the todo object in the permission class.

Comment: I see. But is this the right "DRF" way to do it? I'm sure that this is not the first time such a use case popped up.

Comment: @Krimson IMO this is the DRF way. Validating data in the serializer is the safe way to do it. Object permissions are better when you want to protect existing data.